# How to make a semi-transparent app background with electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, transparent

I'm quite new to Electron and am wondering how i can create the effect where parts of an application are partially transparent, and show a blurred image of the applications below them.
This screenshot of Canary, an email app is a good example of what I mean. [image: screenshot of Canary, a mail app. Notice the semi-transparent blurred background of the sidebar]

(I edited out my emails in preview)

How would I go about creating an effect similar to this in Electron? Specifically, how would I make a `<div>` element show a blurred version of the applications below it? Is this even possible with Electron?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: There's a "plugin" called [electron-vibrancy](https://github.com/arkenthera/electron-vibrancy/blob/master/README.md) that allows you to do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When setting up the browser window in your main.js file, set the vibrancy  option to one of electrons options.

A snippet from `electrons documents` below

```
"vibrancy String (optional) - Add a type of vibrancy effect to the window, only on macOS. 
Can be appearance-based, light, dark, titlebar, selection, menu, popover, sidebar, medium-light or ultra-dark."
```

https://github.com/arkenthera/electron-vibrancy/blob/master/README.md

example js code if using the ultra-dark theme

let mainWindow;

```
const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    vibrancy: 'ultra-dark',
  });
};
```

After setting up the main window's background with the vibrancy set then simply split the window up with a sidebar and the main content. Setting the background color of main to any color you wish leaving the sidebar still with its OSX style transparency

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function on window `setOpacity(number)` where number can be as per your preference.

Comment: This question isn't about opacity; it's about vibrancy/blur.